# Why we have to export the function used by spawn?

Tags: concurrency, erlang

In Erlang and while dealing with process, you have to export the function used in spawn function.

```
-module(echo).
-export([start/0, loop/0]).

start() ->
  spawn(echo, loop, []).
```

The reason from the book "Programming Erlang, 2nd Edition. page 188" is

> ***"Note that we also have to export the argument of spawn from the module. This is a good practice because we will be able to change the internal details of the server without changing the client code."***.

And in the book "Erlang Programming", page 121:

```
-module(frequency).
-export([start/0, stop/0, allocate/0, deallocate/1]). 
-export([init/0]).  

%% These are the start functions used to create and 
%% initialize the server.

start() ->
   register(frequency, spawn(frequency, init, [])).

init() ->
   Frequencies = {get_frequencies(), []}, 
   loop(Frequencies).
```

> ***Remember that when spawning a process, you have to export the init/ 0 function as it is used by the spawn/3 BIF. We have put this function in a separate export clause to distinguish it from the client functions, which are supposed to be called from other modules.***

Would you please explain to me the logic behind that reason?

Comment: Where did you read this reason? Googling it as a phrase only reveals this post. It's not that it's untrue, it just seems extremely partial to me.

Comment: @PaulGuyot "Programming Erlang, 2nd Edition" , page 188

Comment: Then he got it mixed up somewhere or you have misunderstood to what he was referring.

Comment: I am confused. Are you talking about the book by Joe Amstrong? I checked my own copies (P2.0 and P5.0) and the word "internals" does not appear in such a phrase. Besides, he explains export pretty well, including the difference between spawn/1 and spawn/3 (section 8.10, although I disagree with this bit, though).

Comment: @PaulGuyot I expanded the original post.

Comment: This bit was quite unclear and the first edition of the book suggests to hide the functions using `spawn/1` as detailed in my answer. I found this in my copies: *There’s one final improvement we can make. We can hide the spawn and rpc inside the module. This is good practice because we will be able to change the internal details of the server without changing the client code.*

Answer (score 2):

short answer is: spawn is not 'language construction' it's library function.

It means 'spawn' is situated in another module, which does not have access to any functions in your module but exported.

You have to pass to 'spawn' function some way to start your code. It can be function value (ie `spawn(fun() -> (any code you want, including any local functions invocations) end)` ) or module/exported function name/arguments, which is visible from other modules.

Comment: But I'm exporting start function that is already calls spawn.

Comment: Sorry `spawn` is a language construct. It might be in the `erlang` module but it is part of the erlang language, just one that looks like a function call.

Comment: @rvirding Why do you write that spawn is a language construct? It just looks like a BIF to me. erlc -S also suggests otherwise: it makes no difference between `spawn(echo, loop, [])` and `erlang:spoon(echo, loop, [])`.

Comment: @PaulGuyot It does look like a normal function but it is just as much a language construct as `!`. There are others as well, for example `link` and `unlink`. We just couldn't be bothered to dream up special syntax for things which behave like functions. So the compiler translates it to a call to the module `erlang`. Anyway the compiler **never** checks what calls you make at compile-time, everything is left to run-time.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `spawn` you create a new completely ***new*** process with its own environment and thread of execution. This means that you are no longer executing "inside" the module where the `spawn` is called, so you must make an "outside" call into the module. the only functions in a module which can be called from the "outside" are exported functions, hence the spawned function must be exported.

It might seem a little strange seeing you are spawning a function in the same module but this is why.

I think it is important to remember that a module is just code and does not contain any deeper meaning than that, for example like a class in an OO language. So even if you have functions from the same module being executed in different processes, a ***very*** common occurrence, then there is no implicit connection between them. You still have to send messages between processes even if it is from/to functions in the same module.

**EDIT:**

About the last part of your question with the quote about putting export `init/1` in a separate export declaration. There is no need to do this and it has no semantic significance, you can use as many or as few export declarations as you wish. So you could put all the functions in one export declaration or have a separate one for each function; it makes no difference.

The reason to split them is purely visual and for documentation purposes. You typically group functions which go together into separate export declarations to make it easier to see that they are a group. You also typically put "internal" exported functions, functions which aren't meant for the user to directly call, in a separate export declaration. In this case `init/1` has to be exported for the spawn but is not meant to be called directly outside the spawn.

By having the user call the `start/0` function to start the server and not have them explicitly spawn the `init/1` function allows you to change the internals as you wish later on. The user only sees the `start/0` function. Which is what the first quote is trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is quite straightforward. Yet confusion can easily arise as:

- export does not exactly match object-oriented encapsulation and especially public methods;
- several common patterns require to export functions not meant to be called by regular clients.

### What export really does

Export has a very strict meaning: **exported functions are the only functions that can be referred to by their fully qualified name**, i.e. by module, function name and arity.

For example:

```
-module(m).
-export([f/0]).
f() -> foo.
f(_Arg) -> bar.
g() -> foobar.
```

You can call the first function with an expression such as `m:f()` but this wouldn't work for the other two functions. `m:f(ok)` and `m:g()` will fail with an error.

For this reason, the compiler will warn in the example above that f/1 and g/0 are not called and cannot be called (they are *unused*).

**Functions can always be called from outside a module**: functions are values and you can refer to a local function (within a module), and pass this value outside. For example, you can spawn a new process by using a non-exported function, using [`spawn/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-1). You could rewrite your example as follows:

```
start() ->
    spawn(fun loop/0).
```

This doesn't require to export loop. Joe Armstrong in other editions of *Programming Erlang* explicitely suggests to transform the code as above to avoid exporting `loop/0`.

### Common patterns requiring an export

Because exports are the only way to refer to a function by name from outside a module, there are two common patterns that require exported functions even if those functions are not part of a *public API*.

The example you mention is whenever you want to call a **library function that takes a MFA**, i.e. a module, a function name and a list of arguments. These library functions will refer to the function by its fully qualified name. In addition to [`spawn/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn-3), you might encounter [`timer:apply_after/4`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_after-4).

Likewise, you can write functions that take MFA arguments, and call the function using [`apply/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#apply-3).

Sometimes, there are variants of these library functions that directly take a 0-arity function value. This is the case with spawn, as mentioned above. apply/1 doesn't make sense as you would simply write `F()`.

The other common case is **behavior callbacks**, and especially [OTP behaviors](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/des_princ.html#id60055). In this case, you will need to export the callback functions which are of course referred to by name.

Good practice is to use separate export attributes for these functions to make it clear these functions are not part of the regular interface of the module.

### Exports and code change

**There is a third common case for using exports beyond a public API: code changes**.

Imagine you are writing a loop (e.g. a server loop). You would typically implement this as following:

```
-module(m).
-export([start/0]).
start() -> spawn(fun() -> loop(state) end).
loop(State) ->
    NewState = receive ...
    ...
    end,
    loop(NewState). % not updatable !
```

This code cannot be updated, as the loop will never exit the module. The proper way would be to export loop/1 and perform a fully qualified call:

```
-module(m).
-export([start/0]).
-export([loop/1]).
start() -> spawn(fun() -> loop(state) end).
loop(State) ->
    NewState = receive ...
    ...
    end,
    ?MODULE:loop(NewState).
```

Indeed, when you refer to an exported function using its fully qualified name, **the lookup is always performed against the latest version of the module**. So this trick allows to jump to the newer version of the code at every iteration of the loop. Code updates are actually quite complex, and OTP, with its behaviors, does it right for you. It typically uses the same construct.

Conversely, when you call a function passed as a value, this is always from the version of the module that created this value. Joe Armstrong argues this is an advantage of `spawn/3` over `spawn/1` in a dedicated section of his book (8.10, Spawning with MFAs). He writes:

> Most programs we write use `spawn(Fun)` to create a new process. This is fine provided we don’t want to dynamically upgrade our code. Sometimes we want to write code that can be upgraded as we run it. If we want to make sure that our code can be dynamically upgraded, then we have to use a different form of spawn.

This is far-fetched as when you spawn a new process, it starts immediately, and an update is unlikely to occur between the start of the new process and the moment the function value is created. Besides, Armstrong's statement is partly untrue: to make sure the code can dynamically be upgraded, `spawn/1` will work as well (cf example above), the trick is not to use `spawn/3`, but to perform a fully qualified call (Joe Armstrong describes this in another section). `spawn/3` has other advantages over `spawn/1`.

Still, the difference between passing a function by value and by name explains why there is no version of `timer:apply_after/4` that takes a function by value, since there is a delay and the function by value might be old when the timer fires. Such a variant would actually be dangerous because at most two versions of a module: the current one of the old one. If you reload a module more than once, processes trying to call even older versions of the code will be killed. For this reason, you would often prefer MFAs and their exports to function values.

Answer (score -1):

If you're wondering why you have to export anything and not have everything visible by default, it's because it's clearer to the user which functions they should call if you hide all the ones they shouldn't.  That way, if you change your mind on the implementation, people using your code won't notice.  Otherwise, there may be someone who is using a function that you want to change or eliminate.

For example, say you have a module:

```
-module(somemod).

useful() ->
    helper().
helper() ->
    i_am_helping.
```

And you want to change it to:

```
-module(somemod).

useful() ->
    betterhelper().
betterhelper() ->
    i_am_helping_more.
```

If people should only be calling `useful`, you should be able to make this change.  However, if everything was exported, people might be depending on `helper` when they shouldn't be.  This change will break their code when it shouldn't.